# How to replace a character with string in Span<char>?

Tags: c#, string, char

I'm currently trying to replace few specific characters with other characters in `Span<char>`. In my case, I'm trying to replace a space with `_` and `'` with `&27`. Should I just

```
Span<char>.ToString().Replace("'", "&27")
```

at end of the method?

```
Span<char> span = stackalloc char[byte.MaxValue];
for (int i = 0, c = name.Length; i < c; i++) {
    char old = name[i];
    span[i] = old switch {
        ' ' => '_',
        '\'' => char.MinValue,
        _ => name[i]
    };

    if (span[i] is char.MinValue) {
        ReadOnlySpan<char> a = span[(i + 1)..^2];
        span[i] = '&';
        span[i + 1] = '2';
        span[i + 2] = '7';
        span[(i + 3)..^2] = a;
    }
}

return span.ToString();
```

I tried that, but Visual Studio gives an error at `span[(i + 3)..^2]`.

Comment: Why not replace the characters in the string first, then allocate them to the span?